# EFCore 5 from EFCore 3.1.4: Problem with FromSqlInterpolated() and IQueryable<string>

Tags: entity-framework-core

Please, help me to solve problem after migration from EF 3.1.4 to EF 5.0.3. When I try to set `DataContext` as a collection of strings, next message appears. (Collection has taken using by next expression with stored procedure):

```
public virtual IQueryable<string> PR_HLP_GetHelpMessage(string lang, string controllerName)
{ 
   var coll = this.Set<HelpMessageModel().FromSqlInterpolated($"ProcedureName {langParameter}, {controllerNameParameter}");
     _context = s.Select(x => x.Message);
       return _context;
}
```

After getting collection, I applied "Select" (to bind property to `DataContext`) and the next exception appears:

> InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

When I cast this to `AsEnumerable()`, it works well, but EF Core 3.1.4 did not have this problem.

[image]